# How to turn off automatic formatting to date in Excel

Tags: excel, date, formatting, excel-formula

I have Excel table with 145 columns and 13000 rows. Currently all data is set to "Text" format. There are few thousands of records where I need to replace '**,**' by '**.**'. I have numbers in the form:

```
1,2 3,2 4,1
```

I need to convert them to:

```
1.2 3.2 4.1
```

I try to replace all commas with dots in the whole table. The problem is that Excel automatically converts numbers to date after replacement. But before replacement I set all table format to "Text". Even though Excel converted everything to date I tried to apply "Text' or 'Number' format after replacement. It did not help. All data is spoiled and completely different numbers displayed.

How to replace all commas in entire table without automatic tranformation to date?

Comment: Try `=--SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",".")` this will change them to numbers.

Comment: For example 2,8 is replaced with 42218. I just need 2.8. And also do I need to apply this formula for all of my 145 columns?

Comment: With formulas you can't change the cell it is referencing directly, so you would need to start at the first empty cell to the right and reference the furthest left top cell then drag the formula the same number of columns and then rows.  Then highlight everything copy and paste just the values over the original.  In vba this would be easier.  As you can change the values in place.

Comment: Another  thing to keep in mind is if you put a ' in front of cell contents, Excel automatically formats the contents to text no matter what is after it or how the cell was formatted previously. So, " '1.2 3.2 4.1 " (without the double quotes) would be formatted how you were wanting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Substitute formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",".")
```

This will leave it as text.

With formulas you can't change the cell it is referencing directly, so you would need to start at the first empty cell to the right and reference the furthest left top cell then drag the formula the same number of columns and then rows. Then highlight everything copy and paste just the values over the original.